# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I am trying to auto accept ssh-rsa key through Plink via python. But I am getting error

Below is my code

```
def __init__(self, ipaddress, option, user, password, command=""):
    """
    Constructor creates the connection to the host.
    """
    self.ipaddress = ipaddress
    self.option = option
    self.user = user
    self.password = password
    self.command = command
    self.key()

def key(self):
    command1 = ['echo', 'y']
    process1 = subprocess.Popen(command1,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    command2 = ['plink', '-ssh', self.option, '-pw', self.password, '%s@%s'%(self.user, self.ipaddress), '\"exit\"']
    process2 = subprocess.Popen(command2,stdin=process1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

def sendSingleCommand(self, command):
    """
    Set up a ssh connection a device, send command, close connection and return stdout,stderr tuple.
    """
    try:
        print("plink -ssh %s -pw %s %s@%s %s" \
                % (self.option, self.password, self.user, self.ipaddress, command))
        self.process = subprocess.Popen("plink -ssh %s -pw %s %s@%s %s" \
                % (self.option, self.password, self.user, self.ipaddress, command), shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But i am getting error for Key() function for the line process1. Below is the error :

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__  
Error:     restore_signals, start_new_session)  
Error:   File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child  
Error:     startupinfo)  
Error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 2):

In Windows , to use `echo` in subprocess, you would need to use `shell=True` . This is because echo is not a separate executable, but rather a built-in command for the windows command line. Example -

```
process1 = subprocess.Popen(command1,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

Also, please do note, you should only use `shell=True` when absolutely necessary (as in this case , to use `echo` in windows in subprocess).

---

Though as a whole, you can directly pass in `y`  to your second command using `PIPE` and `.communicate()`. Example -

```
def key(self):
    command2 = ['plink', '-ssh', self.option, '-pw', self.password, '%s@%s'%(self.user, self.ipaddress), '\"exit\"']
    process2 = subprocess.Popen(command2,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, _ = process.communicate(b'y')
```

Comment: Worth to add that `shell=True` is a security risk. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: Yes, correct . Added an alternative approach that doesn't use `shell=True` .