# PyInstaller issue, not running after building

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller

I have a wx Python program which I have attempting to build into a .exe with PyInstaller. I have installed Pywin32 and Pyinstaller, I've used both the below to package up the Python file.

```
pyinstaller andro.py

pyinstaller -F andro.py
```

Both .exe files when double clicked flash up a cmd box briefly then disappear.

Trying to run both from cmd gives me the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1737, in <module>
 File "c:\pentesting\andro\build\andro\out00-PYZ.pyz\wx._core", line 8628, in __in
it__
 File "c:\pentesting\andro\build\andro\out00-PYZ.pyz\wx._core", line 8196, in _BootstrapApp
 File "<string>", line 1732, in OnInit
 File "<string>", line 298, in __init__
 File "<string>", line 308, in startConf
 File "<string>", line 835, in deviceExists
 File "c:\pentesting\andro\build\andro\out00-PYZ.pyz\subprocess", line 710, in __i
nit__
 File "c:\pentesting\andro\build\andro\out00-PYZ.pyz\subprocess", line 958, in _execute_child
   WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Line 1732 is:

```
 frame = Main(None, -1, 'Andro')
```

Line 298 is:

```
 self.startConf()
```

Line 308 is:

```
 stdout = self.deviceExists()
```

Line 835 is:

```
p = Popen(params, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Following the trail, they all lead to the deviceExists() function, specifically line 835, the 'p = Popen' line:

```
def deviceExists(self):
    params = [toolsDir + "\\adb.exe", "devices"]
    p = Popen(params, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    return stdout
```

The program runs and works fine when launched from cmd, python andro.py, so unsure of the problem, is anyone able to offer any idea?

Comment: What is the `toolsDir` ?

Comment: tools for the program to run. it's defined as global.

Comment: Is it string, integer or a list? Did you try with `shell=True` ?

Comment: I did try, and shell=True seemed to work, but why is this the case?

Comment: This might help you to understand the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32268447/2382792